# Is the buffer distance the radius or diameter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, buffer, point-in-polygon

I have created circles using the buffer tool ArcGIS Pro using point features. Is the distance specified when making a buffer the radius around the point, or is it the diameter? I have entered 1 meter as my distance.

Here is a screenshot of what the buffer window looks like:
[image]

Comment: Does the manual help https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm?

Answer (score 4):

The buffer includes all the area that is within the specified distance from the source feature. Point feature buffers happen to be circular and the distance from the point, at the centre of the circle, to the edge of the buffer (the circumference of the circle) is of course the radius of that circle.

Consider that buffers can be generated for other feature types, not just points.  Now imagine what it would look like when generating a buffer around a complicated polygon shape. The buffer includes all the area that is within the specified distance from the polygon. The whole notion of radius/diameter doesn't even make sense for buffering a polygon.

The same logic applies to buffering points.  It's just incidental that points result in circular buffers.